# Dividing by half in ruby to create an effective calculator

Tags: ruby, calculator

For the past while I've been working on a calculator, but have run into problems when needing to divide by a half. I'll add the offending bit of code along with a loop to keep it open below.

```
on = true
while on == true do
    half = 1.0 / 2.0
    puts ("FUNCTION IN TESTING MODE, DO NOT EXPECT IT TO FUNCTION PROPERLY")
    puts ("Area of a triangle")
    print("What is the legnth of the base? ").to_i
    base = gets.chomp("base")
    print("\nWhat is the height? ")
    height = gets.chomp("height").to_i
    PreAreaT = base * height
    AreaT = PreAreaT * half
    puts("The area of the triangle is #{AreaT}")
end
```

So essentially, how on Earth do I get the program to display an answer, rather than outputting nothing for the answer?

EDIT:As it would turn out the code above is improperly done. I've spent nearly two weeks asking myself why it wouldn't work only to find I had .to_i after a print statement rather than the input.

Comment: Tangential note: to divide by half means to multiply by two. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `to_i` call is switched around here.

```
print("What is the legnth of the base? ").to_i
base = gets.chomp("base")
```

Should be the other way 'round.

```
print("What is the length of the base? ")
base = gets.chomp("base").to_i
```

Further, [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) will attempt to remove any occurrences of `base` or `height` from the string.  Be sure that you're intention is to remove those occurrences; if you want to remove whitespace, you'll have to take a different approach.

Comment: You posted this just as I figured it out, thanks anyhow. I feel a bit silly for letting this go for weeks on end. Also i used gets.chomp as it's the only input way I know how to use in Ruby, for I'm new to the language.

Comment: I meant that `gets.chomp("base")` may not be doing what you think it is - all it's doing is removing `base` from what you read in.  Be cautious about its usage and be sure that it's in line with what you expect.

Comment: In addition: Do not use `PreAreaT` and `AreaT` as variables in Ruby. They are constants, and in the second and further iterations of the loop you will get `warning: already initialized constant`. Variables in Ruby have to start with lowercase, and are by convention in snake case: `pre_area_t` and `area_t` would be fine.